# How to tag monosemous words

Tags: java, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

i am using JAWS-Java API for wordnet searching.i have been searching alot but unable to find how to count the number of senses the given word can have.Is there any function for it? And after finding how the monosemous words can be tagged.

Comment: what do mean "tagged"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a word belongs to only one synset, it has only one meaning -> monosemy.

JAWS Code snippet:

```
WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets("monosemous");
if(synsets.length == 0) //not found
else if(synsets.length == 1) //monosemous word
```

PS: "monosemous" is a monosemous word.

Comment: Thank you for your help. do you know anything about scoring function used in iterative word sense disambiguation.i wanted to know how the monosemous word found by above method can be used to disambiguate the remaining words in the sentence in increasing order of their degree of polysemy.

Comment: TLDR; frame that in proper question/example. I'm sure somebody will be a help.